# How to write a script that can take input from stdout

Tags: pipe, stdout, stdin

I want to be able to write a script that can take `stdout` as an argument, if anything is piped into it (ultimately, I would like it to be polymorphic) -

The trouble is, I have searched and searched for how to do this with no avail - lots of alternative suggestions about how to do other things that are not - this:

`cat /var/log/some.log | grep something | awk '{print $1 $6 $8}' | myscript`

Why do that, instead of? : `myscript $(!!)` 
At this point, solely to prove that it is possible...

I know that you can 'read variable' in a script, but say I don't care about the lines - let's say, I want to accept the whole of it as a blob of text and do something with it in the script -

Do I really have to :

```
while read x; do
stdin=$stdin" "$x;
done;
```

solely in order to read from STDIN ?

There must be a better way ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read all of stdin into a shell script, usually you just capture it into a temp file:

```
TMPFILE=$(mktemp -- "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/${0##*/}.$$.XXXXXX") || exit
cat > "$TMPFILE"
# Script works with $TMPFILE and its contents,
# ultimately writing everything to stdout.
rm -f -- "$TMPFILE"
```

Even system utilities do things very much like this. `sort` has to have all of stdin before it can print anything to stdout, for example.

Comment: This seems to be the most simple solution for doing this - and I'm sure this is what I'm going to go with -

Answer (score 3):

You can read from stdout by redirecting input from file descriptor 1. Stdout is file descriptor 1 by definition. The fact that file descriptor 1 is used for output is a matter of convention, not a technical obligation. However it's a bizarre thing to do which is bound to confuse the people who use your script.

```
read line <&1
```

If you want to read a whole file, use `cat`. To stuff the content into a variable, use a command substitution.

```
whole_input=$(cat)
whole_input_from_stdout=$(cat <&1)
```

Some shells let you write `$(</dev/stdin)` as a slightly more efficient shortcut for `$(cat)`.

Note that this strips trailing newlines. This behavior is built into command substitution. To retain trailing newlines, hide them behind another character and remove that character.

```
whole_input=$(cat; echo .); whole_input=${whole_input%?}
```

The shell variable will only contain the data up to the first null byte, if there is a null byte in the input. With some shells, you'll get all the data with the null bytes stripped. Shells can't deal with binary data. Zsh is an exception, it retains the null bytes.

Comment: while this is certainly the most elegant solution, it seems that that method does not actually preserve the newlines - - -

Comment: @rm-vanda `$(cat)` preserves the newlines except for the trailing ones. The two-step process I describe afterwards preserves all newlines.

Comment: See [What's wrong with var=$(</dev/stdin) to read stdin into a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716438)

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean that you want to write your script so it can process the stdout of a command either from its stdin or in its arguments.

Then, the obvious way to do it is to check the number of arguments.

If your script processes its input in a shell variable:

```
#! /bin/sh -

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
  # arguments joined with space, the first character of $IFS
  input="$*"
else
  input=$(cat) # stdin without the trailing newline characters
fi

printf 'I got "%s"\n' "$input"
```

Or you could read each non-empty lines of stdin into the positional parameters (`$@`: `$1`, `$2`...) if not passed any argument:

```
#! /bin/sh -
NL='
'
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  set -o noglob
  IFS=$NL
  set -- $(cat) # split+glob with splitting on NL and glob disabled
fi

echo "I got $# arguments:"
[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf ' - "%s"\n' "$@"
```

Or if it processes its input as a stream:

```
#! /bin/sh -
main() {
  # process standard input as a stream 
  grep -i foo | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
  # as an example
}

if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
  # feed arguments as separate lines through a pipe:
  printf '%s\n' "$@" | main
else
  # stdin just passed along
  main
fi
```

All can be invoked with:

```
cmd | the-script
```

Or:

```
the-script "$(cmd)"
```

(don't forget the quotes without which the output of `cmd` would be subject to split+glob!)

See also:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)
- [What's wrong with var=$(</dev/stdin) to read stdin into a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716438) (in case you'd be tempted to use that in place of `input=$(cat)`).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to get the whole lump if you don't want to - you can chunk out stdin and work it as a stream if you like. I did some googling, though, and I don't think I can offer you any advice on how to change the sex of your script, or whatever it is you meant by *polymorphic*.

In any case, I typically find that putting the whole of input aside in some storage is rarely what I'm after. I usually want to handle it in delimited lumps of some kind. Here's an example of how you can get input of any kind split out into 4k chunks per `while` loop iteration:

```sh
splitin(){
    dd obs=4k | { j=$1 f=$2;shift 2 && 
    while dd bs=4k count=1 of="$f"  &&
          [ -s "$f" ] 
    do    "$j" "$@" < "$f"
    done
};  }
```

...which is a function you might call from your shell script with the name of a some job you want to perform on 4k input intervals and the name of a temp file it can use to store each latest chunk. Like:

```sh
splitin handle_chunk /tmp/work/chunk \
        other args to pass on as appropriate
```

Comment: Awesome. I will spend time dissecting this - but this is a bit more complex than what I was looking for - 
But thanks! this is a really good answer...

Comment: @rm-vanda what are you looking for? and why do you want to give your script a sex-change?

Comment: Hah! 
I wasn't really looking to read it in chunks - the answer i accepted was precisely what I was looking for -
But this snippet is quite complex, and I will break it down and learn from it So thank you !

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that you have to consider separately 1) the device, 2) the data stream interface in general, 3) the line reader-writer interface in particular, 4) the semantic.

`stdout` is a technical endpoint private to your process and with the same lifecycle, to write byte stream, not to read. You can duplicate a reference to it so it is referred to by another name, its capability is always **output**. It is created and deleted with the process. `stdin` is an equivalent on which you read byte stream. Its capability is always **input**. Depending on underlying device, they may have both capabilities, but the standard and reliable model is agnostic about that.

A **byte stream** is a general interface that accept two signals on its write-end: `put`, `close` and emits two corresponding signals on its read-end: `byte`, `EOD`. When the write-end (e.g `stdout`) receive `put`, the read-end has to get a `byte`. When the write-end accept `close`, the read-end get `EOD`. `EOD` (`close`) is sent either explicitly when the `stdout` descriptor is closed by `exec >&-` or when the process terminates.

A **line reader or writer** is a special way to use a byte stream, with an additional signal `newline`, but it is not inherent to `stdin` nor `stdout`, it is just data transformed to and from **text lines** because it is convenient, maniable and robust. This is a **line protocol** or discipline, historic standard, iterable and reasonably **agnostic**. The `newline` signal is a convention ; whatever it may be, it has to take one value. There is no alternative unless relying on another state but the device has only two states, opened or closed. In other words, the byte stream is device driven while the line reader is data driven.

Given that, supposing you want to communicate between two processes *via* a pipe, the minimal signal the speaker can send to the listener is `byte` and `EOD`, but this **can't be done by iteration** as you would do with text lines because once closed (`EOD` sent), the file descriptor is **not reusable** (even while it may be hackable). But, **as long as you don't need to iterate**, you can rely on `EOD`.

Then, let's be realistic : **polymorphism** as you say, is not a matter of raw data in a byte stream, if you lose the iterable line model in doing that. Polymorphism is a matter of **model** on top of a simple iterable protocol, say line discipline, on top of a raw protocol, say byte stream, that can be implemented on socket, pipe, file, tape, printer or whatever.

However, on top of the stream model, there are only two iteration controls : either you know in advance how much to read, or you read one by one until a signal. Knowing that, you can adopt the discipline you prefer on top of the raw stream instead of the text lines, it is always a matter of **parser**. A parser is a machine that read a stream and builds other objects in its own language model.

And, to be an acceptable interface on top of a stream, it has to resume parsing at the exact point where the last iteration left it, sequentially and forward.

Now that we know that **polymorphism + iteration => sequential parser**, we can come back to standard and be very satisfied. What we need is **K**eep **I**t **S**imple **S**tupid.

Comment: fds 0, 1, 2 are not *created by the kernel*, they're created like any other fd by a process using `open()` / `dup()` / `pipe()`, `accept()` or anything that allocates a fd

Comment: There's nothing stopping fd 1 to be open for reading. When opened on a tty device, it's actually generally open in read+write mode and often shares the same *open file description* with fds 0 and 2.

Comment: Careful not to confuse stdout / stdin with `/dev/stdout`, `/dev/stdin` which are special features of some OSes to expose stdin / stdout or sometimes the same file as open on stdin / stdout as file paths.

Comment: Thx @StéphaneChazelas for your remarks.