# tee /dev/stderr inside script truncates output file if you redirect stderr

Tags: bash, io-redirection, tee

Given a script like below if I try to redirect stderr to a file, then the file is truncated at the point `tee` is used:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

set -eux
echo before
echo '{ "foo": "bar" }' | tee /dev/stderr | jq .foo
echo after
$ ./test.sh 2> log
before
"bar"
after
$ cat log 
{ "foo": "bar" }
+ echo after
```

The `log` file should have all of the stderr output. Everything I see if I run the same script without redirecting:

```
$ ./test.sh
+ echo before
before
+ echo '{ "foo": "bar" }'
+ tee /dev/stderr
+ jq .foo
{ "foo": "bar" }
"bar"
+ echo after
after
```

So why do I only see the lines that come *after* `tee`? Using `2>>` doesn't seem to help.

I Don't understand why is this happening. How can I tee the output while still having the ability to redirect the whole script stderr to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to how `/dev/stderr`, or rather, `/proc/$pid/fd/$num` works in Linux. There, opening `/dev/stderr` does *not* duplicate file descriptor 2, but instead accesses the resource that fd is connected to directly.

So, since `tee` normally truncates the file it writes to, so it does with `tee /dev/stderr`. In your case, it's pretty much the same as doing `tee log`.

See [What's wrong with var=$(</dev/stdin) to read stdin into a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/716438/170373) for further details.

---

That's only an issue on Linux. E.g. on macOS, it works as you'd assume it does. A somewhat compressed example:

```
linux$ bash -xc 'false; echo "truncated?" | tee /dev/stderr >/dev/null; true' 2>log
linux$ cat log
truncated?
+ true
```

vs.

```
mac$ bash -xc 'false; echo "truncated?" | tee /dev/stderr >/dev/null; true' 2>log
mac$ cat log
+ false
+ tee /dev/stderr
+ echo 'truncated?'
truncated?
+ true
```

Now, to make that work, you'd need to avoid using `/dev/stderr`, and instead somehow use something like `>&2` which tells the shell to duplicate file descriptor 2.

I think you could do that with `tee >( cat >&2 )`. That's a bit convoluted, but you can't tell `tee` to use an existing fd, you need to give it a *filename*, and due to the above issue, it can't be one that refers to the script's stderr directly.

However, it has the issue that the `cat` runs in the background, which can make the output from it delayed, like here:

```
linux$ bash -xc 'false; echo "truncated?" | tee >(cat >&2) >/dev/null; true' 2>log
$ cat log
+ false
+ echo 'truncated?'
+ tee /dev/fd/63
++ cat
+ true
truncated?
```

Note that just `tee -a /dev/stderr` doesn't help, since while that means anything `tee` writes goes to the end of the file, anything written through the original stderr does *not*, but follows the write position of that file description. So you get things like this:

```
$ bash -xc 'false; echo "truncated?" | tee -a /dev/stderr >/dev/null; true' 2>log
$ cat log
+ false
+ echo 'truncated?'
+ tee -a /dev/stderr
+ true
ed?
```

where the last `+ true<nl>` (from the script's stderr) is written over the `truncated?` (from `tee`). You need to also make the original redirection an appending one, i.e. `bash ... 2>>log`.

Or just make the original redirection go to a pipe instead of the file. With a pipe, `/dev/stderr` works more like you'd think, since pipes don't have a write position, and can't be truncated.
Just the way to do that is a bit convoluted, you need something like `2> >(cat > log)`.

Comment: > Or just make the original redirection go to a pipe instead of the file. 
Could I instead do something inside the script file with e.g. exec to run stderr output through a pipe?

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote this I realized I probably can use the `tee -a` option.

Still I don't quite understand why doing `tee /dev/stderr` would truncate the redirect file